# How to Style Elements with Component-Level CSS using Style Loaders?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scope, create-react-app

So for my create-react-app, I'm using style loaders to make use of component-level CSS like so:

```
:local(.form) {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px 35px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

However, how do I do that with this:

```
nav {
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: white;
}

    /* The icon of our app */
    nav a .library-music {
        line-height: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        color: orange;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
```

Do you see the problem? I cannot do ":local(nav a .library-music). In other words, what is the correct syntax, or approach to apply localized CSS to non-class elements?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
nav a :local(.library-music) {
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

your `nav` and `a` tags are not affected by the css compiler, so you only need to apply the `:local()` modifier to the class name.

Comment: And if it were multiple classes, It'd be 

:local(class1) :local(class2) { ... }

Correct?